# How can I compile Razor templates on demand?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

[Antaris RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) supports a simple compiler with a straight forward [templating syntax](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/TemplateBasics.html):

```
string template = "<div>Hello @Model.Name</div>";
var model = new Person { Name = "Matt" };

string result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "key", typeof(Person), model);
```

However, this project hasn't been updated since Jan 2018.  Can I do this same type of compilation somehow using [ASP.NET Core Razor SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?  I have a .NET core C# project that I want to run this in.

I am looking for a hello world example of taking a string template as input and compiling it.  If there's any confusion see the code example I posted above.

Comment: So far the closest thing I've found is: https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/binding-razor-view-templates-programatically

Comment: That solution uses https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine which hasn't been updated in over a year.